# Teamcity / Bitbucket - Build a Pull Requests merge commit before merge

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, bitbucket, pull-request

I have configured a Bitbucket Server and Teamcity as CI.

Teamcity also builds all commits, which does work very well.

Now I want to build the "Merge commit" which will be generated of a Pull request, before the Pull Request gets merged.

Comment: This article gives step by step examples of how to configure the behavior you need for various platforms, including Bitbucket: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/pull-requests.html#VCS-specific+settings

Answer (score 0):

bitbucket creates `pull-requests/<pr number>/from` branch for every created pull request.

so you can add to vcs root branch specification rule "get only PR branches"

[image]

and then add vcs trigger to run it automatically on every new commit in pull-request

**UPDATE**
Bitbucket dropped support for this in v7.0, so this no longer is a fix.

Comment: This would build the heads of the pull request's source branches, not the resulting merged code